# VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED vs VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL as initial layout for Framebuffer attachment

Tags: image, layout, attachment, vulkan

I saw that it is recommended to set initial layout as VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED , because we really don't care for its content when it is used as target for the next rendering process.

But if I know that an image is attached for being color target, isn't it better to set it to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL which tells the driver exactly what it is going to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial layout for a render pass attachment is the layout the image is in *before* the renderpass starts. You're not saying "put this image into this layout"; you're saying "the image *already is* in this layout". So unless that image is already in the color attachment layout, that's not the appropriate layout to set as the initial layout. If you set the layout to be "undefined", you're basically saying "I don't care."

Each subpass specifies the layout that the attachments it uses will be put into during that subpass. So when the first subpass that uses this attachment starts, it will perform a layout transition from the initial layout to the subpass's layout.

If your render pass clears the image, then the image's initial layout does not matter. The clear operation will overwrite the texture's data (not that any actual writing will take place to do this, mind you), and when the first subpass that uses the attachment starts, the data written will be in that subpass's layout.

It shouldn't be any slower than using the same layout for the initial layout and the first subpass layout. So long as you're clearing the image.